# How to add a bounded piece of text in Swing and test for overflow?

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts

I want to display pieces of text of various sizes in a size-bounded (fullscreen) Swing application.
I tried to use a `JTextField`, but its size increases vertically when the text is too long, making the text going out of the bounds of the screen.

Considering this, I want:

1. to bound the size of the text field such that it does not overextends when setting the text in and
2. check whether the text is too long for this given size (e.g. for lowering the size of the font).

Can you help me to overcome these issues, please?

Comment: (1) sounds like JFormattedTextField, like JTextField documentation suggests. (2) won't be built-in, you'll need a custom piece of code.

Comment: Why use a text component at all?  We can render the text direct to a `Graphics` object, and doing it that way, we can scale it to whatever size exactly fits the available space.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do something the wrong way. Give a concrete example.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
Deltharis, I would like to have some nice properties of the JTextField, such as printing text on multiple lines.
Andrew, the Graphics is a possible track but keeps us to the original issue : I cannot tell whether a given text will go beyond predefined bounds.
User1803551, here is a concrete example: I want a function that takes into parameter a text, a font and a space and tells whether the text fits the space. For instance printing "hello" with a small font in a 100*10 pixels box returns true. If the font is set to 200, the function returns false (too long text).